# leftpadding using "current()" inside "format-number()" in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have an xml element `<RandomNumber>` which string size is always either 8 or 9 digits. If the element has a string-length greater than 1, I wish to left pad it with a zero if its size is 8 instead of 9 digits. So I wrote the following code:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="STRING_LENGTH">
      <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="current()[string-length(RandomNumber) >= $STRING_LENGTH]/RandomNumber">
    <xsl:element name="leftPNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(current(), '000000000')"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the input:

```
<RandomNumbers>
    <RandomNumber>11223366</RandomNumber>
</RandomNumbers>
```

The intended output should be:

```
<leftPNumber>011223366</leftPNumber>
```

For some reason it doesnt work as intended, but doesnt fault either. It just creates the new element with the original number in it, without adding the additional "0".
Is this because im using current() inside the "format-number"?
 If so, what alternative can I use?

Cheers,

Jesper

Comment: Have you missed out some other templates from your XSLT, as you have a named template, but nothing calling it. Also, can you edit your question to show your input XML please? You mention `randomnumber` in your question, but the XSLT checks for `randomNumber` which is different due to case-sensitivity. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll add the requested info and make sure I post that directly next time I ask a question.

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example. The input you show is not well-formed XML, and your stylesheet cannot possibly do what you say it does.

Comment: I hope my last edit is well-formed xml. My question is mostly about whether I can use "current()" inside "format-number".

Comment: Your stylesheet still makes no sense.

Comment: Note that at the top level of a path expression, current() can always be replaced by "." (and vice versa)

Comment: Why not simply write `<xsl:variable name="STRING_LENGTH" select="1">`?

Comment: Another way to pad a number to 9 digits is `substring(1000000000 + $num), 2)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I can really use these  :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is mostly about whether I can use "current()" inside "format-number"

Yes, you can - provided your context node is the node holding the value you want to format.

For example, given:

**XML**

```
<RandomNumbers>
    <RandomNumber>5</RandomNumber>
    <RandomNumber>56</RandomNumber>
    <RandomNumber>567</RandomNumber>
</RandomNumbers>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/RandomNumbers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="RandomNumber">
            <leftPNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(current(), '000000000')"/>
            </leftPNumber>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RandomNumbers>
  <leftPNumber>000000005</leftPNumber>
  <leftPNumber>000000056</leftPNumber>
  <leftPNumber>000000567</leftPNumber>
</RandomNumbers>
```